# Nested routes (/:foo/:bar) with parameters do not render, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So, I'm not sure if I should've structured my app different or if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I'm a bit confused, but let's explain first things first.

In the first navigation level, there are 4 pages - and for every page, there is a detail page.

- Home
- Article-Category 1

  - Detail page
- Article-Category 2

  - Detail page
- Article-Category 3

  - Detail page

The *article category* pages are exactly the same. They all hold a list (`<ul><li><Link></Link></li><li>...</ul>`) of 10-20 articles, so I actually just created one component, the *article category* component.

To make this work, the main navigation of the app holds `<Link>`'s which have a param called `page` passed to the *article category* component. Depending on this parameter, the view looks for the articles in an array and uses another component to render them as a list.

The article array itself holds the name of the the article and the parameter *article name*, f.e. *this-is-an-article*. I'm passing the article name parameter to the detail component which looks, depending on this and the page parameter, for the correct article.

Okay, so I hope this is clear. Now, this is my **react-router configuration**:

```js
export default (
    <Route path="/" handler={App}>
        {/* Home */}
        <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home}/>

        {/* Page */}
        <Route name="category" path=":category" handler={Category}>
            <Route name="category.article" path=":article" handler={Article} />
        </Route>

        {/* Not found */}
        <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
    </Route>
);
```

.. but this doesn't work. If I click on an article link which has the correct parameters, nothing happens - well, the URL changes, but nothing else.. and the navigation menu item stays active, which is good. I at least know the parameters are correct because when I change my route confgiruation below `/* Page */` to this:

```js
    <Route name="category" path=":category" handler={Category} />
    <Route name="category.article" path=":category/:article" handler={Article} />
```

it works, but in my main navigation, the naivgation item isn't active anymore when I'm on an article (detail) page, I guess because it's not a child route anymore, so the configuration above this should be the correct one, but it doesn't work..

Below, there are the relevant components and their code + the content array/object. Mind you, the code shown is without any import's (I'm using ES6 with Babel through Webpack), but of course there are some.

**Article component** (renders the article itself)

```js
let Article = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            article: this.props.params.article,
            category: this.props.params.category
        }
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            article: nextProps.params.article,
            category: nextProps.params.category
        })
    },
    render() {
        let content = this._getContent();

        return (
            <div className="page_content page_content-article">
                <ArticleHeader />
                {content}
            </div>
        )
    },
    _getContent() {
        let item;

        for(item of ContentStore[this.state.category]) {
            if(item.name === this.state.article) {
                return item.content;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Category component** (renders the article list with the ArticleList component which just renders  with the category and article params and is the same for each category)

```js
let Index = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            category: this.props.params.category
        };
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            category: nextProps.params.category
        });
    },
    render() {

        return (
            <div className={'page_content page_content-' + this.state.category}>
                <ArticleList articles={this._getArticles()} category={this.state.category} />
            </div>
        )
    },
    _getArticles() {
        return ContentStore[this.state.category];
    }
});
```

**App component**

```js
let App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page">
                <RouteHandler />
                <Navigation />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

**PageStore** (Example of the data - this renders the main navigation)

```js
PageStore: [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Home',
        iconClass: 'home',
        linkTo: 'home',
        params: null
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Category 1',
        iconClass: 'foo',
        linkTo: 'category',
        params: {
            category: 'foo',
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

**ContentStore** (example of the data - this renders the article lists and the detail view as it has it's content)

```js
ContentStore: {
    // "foo" is the category name
    foo: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'article-1',
            linkText: 'Article 1',
            content: (
                <div>
                    lorem ipsum...
                </div>
            )
        },

    ]
}
```

I have two questions:

- What am I missing and how do I make this work?
- SHOULD I actually make this work even if I can or is there a better way? I did it this way because the category pages and the detail page do not have any differences except the content, which comes (yet) from a simple array.

I also ask if I actually should do this because well.. I never see nested routes where both, the parent and the child, have props. Maybe this is actually a bad thing to do.. I'm not sure. If you need any more information, I'm happy to provide it and thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the use of the `:` before the path, I even checked the docs to see if there was an example and couldn't find one, maybe I missed it, the `:` is used for parameters as far as I know. Anyhow, try this:

```
<Route path="/" handler={App}>
    {/* Home */}
    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home}/>

    {/* Page */}
    <Route path="category" handler={Category}>
        <Route path="category/article" handler={Article} />
    </Route>

    {/* Not found */}
    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
</Route>
```

See if that gets the pages working for now and than go from there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, the : is used for parameters - and in my case, :category and :article are, in fact, BOTH parameters. If I do as you wrote it it'll work (I already tried this and similar things, like category/:article - but then I have to create a component and route for every category...) but won't show me any content (which makes sense as I'm getting the content from the "Stores" - and need the parameters to access the "Stores"), it just doesn't work with a parameter in the first AND in the second level of the path and you're right, I never saw an example for this, too...

Comment: .. it works if I use a parameter for :category and not for article or if I use a parameter for :article and not for category - but not both. It's either or and I can't believe there's no possibility to actually do this.

Comment: can you post a working example on github with a link so that I can test locally? Please include whatever files needed to get it working in a local environment.

Comment: Hello Hatem Jaber, I actually found a solution. I had to use another <RouteHandler /> (so I essentially have a <RouteHandler /> in app.js and a <RouteHandler /> in {Category} - and the DefaultRoute is my list view) in my Category pages and re-structure my app a bit. I found this on a JSFiddle, tried it out and it worked. Honestly, I do not know why this isn't documented or if this is the "correct" way to do this: I'll post a more detailed answer next week when I'm back at work.

Comment: I've used nested `<RouteHandler />' in a situation where i want to have tabs on the page and change the tab and the content of the tab. It is undocumented as far as I know, it was something that we had to figure out by experimenting. It is a useful thing to have for nesting content without leaving the current template.